# FFMPEG produces corrupted video outputs on AWS Lambda only

Tags: ffmpeg, amazon-web-services, video-conversion

I've been trying to use **ffmpeg** with AWS Lambda to transcode videos for web. I myself zipped and uploaded ffmpeg and ffprobe as a layer, after testing both of them on my local machine. The exact same problem happens when I use a popular public layer such as [this](https://serverlessrepo.aws.amazon.com/applications/arn:aws:serverlessrepo:us-east-1:145266761615:applications%7Effmpeg-lambda-layer).

Whatever video I try to convert, the outputs either have artifacts, or the video and audio lag, the duration is shorter, etc.

1. [Output](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XMdCJyS_agw) on **lambda function** (python 3.6 runtime), calling ffmpeg with these params:

```
command = ['ffmpeg', '-i', input, '-c:a', 'aac', '-b:a', '128k', '-c:v', 'libx264', '-crf', '23', output]
subprocess.call(command)
```

2. [Output](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=liLTWvkv28A) on my **local machine** (ubuntu), running this command using the same ffmpeg (4.3.1-static):

```
ffmpeg -i input.mov -c:a aac -b:a 128k -c:v libx264 -crf 23 output.mp4
```

What might be the cause of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the issues by changing the runtime from python 3.6 to the new **python 3.8**.

(I don't have a clue as to why it didn't work before and it does now).